# Finding unique number list from large data set in 2D integer vector in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, unique, c++98

I have function that is called dynamically after the regualar interval of time. I reads form file **Car_Id** from **1 to 50** and **Daily_Distance_Tarvel** in for 100 week from **1 to 700 days.**

```
car=1
 Daily_Distance_Km=138
 car=1
 Daily_Distance_Km=239
 car=1
 Daily_Distance_Km=440
 car=1
 Daily_Distance_Km=241
 car=1
 Daily_Distance_Km=462
 car=1
 Daily_Distance_Km=432
 car=1
 Daily_Distance_Km=404
 car=2
 Daily_Distance_Km=435
 car=2
 Daily_Distance_Km=514
 car=2
 Daily_Distance_Km=565
 car=1
 Daily_Distance_Km=328
 car=1
 Daily_Distance_Km=138--->repeating
 car=1
 Daily_Distance_Km=401
 car=1
 Daily_Distance_Km=142
 car=1
 Daily_Distance_Km=404--->repeating
 car=2
 Daily_Distance_Km=460
 car=2
 Daily_Distance_Km=472
 car=2
 Daily_Distance_Km=418
 car=2
 Daily_Distance_Km=510
 car=2

.........................
.......................
```

**Issues**

1-My task is to extract all **distinct(unique)** values of for `car=1 to 50` and do further visualization operations in C++.

2-My `car`numbers can come random sequence.

[image]

For getting the unique value i am using

In .h file

```
 static vector < vector <int> > myCarKm;
```

In .cpp file

```
vector < vector <int> > vehicle::myCarKm(50,vector<int>(700,0));   //Globla var
```

My function is:

```
      void func(int car_no,int Daily_Distance_Km){
        
            for(int cCount=0;cCount<=50;cCount++)
            { 
             for(int dKm=0;dKm<=700;;dKm++)
               { 
          
                if(cCount == 0)
                {
                    myCarKm[cCount][dKm]=0;
          
                }
                else if(cCount == car_no)
                {
                    int unique = unique(myCarKm[cCount].begin(),myCarKm[cCount].end());
                    
                    
                    myCarKm[cCount][dKm] = Daily_Distance_Km;
                    cout << "\n cCount=" << cCount;
                    cout<<"\n 2="<<dKm;
                    cout << "\n myCarKm =" << myCarKm[cCount][dKm];
                    
                }else if(cCount != car_no)
                {
                    myCarKm[cCount][dKm] = 0;
                   // cout<<"\n 3="<<dKm;
                }
            }
        }
 }
```

**Objective**
My objective is to save **all distict**  **all available** value of `Daily_Distance_Km` in c++ for each `car_no` from 1 to 50 which are availbale .How i can save this **distict avilable** record in  `static` vector **myCarKm** and skip **not available** values.

Comment: What about using a `std::set<std::pair<car_no, distance>>` instead?

Comment: Or a `std::map<int, int>` and not use `std::vector`?.  If you did that, the code becomes much shorter and super simple.  A `std::map` by design does not store duplicates (the same with a `std::set`)

Comment: Note that you have a variation of the [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/).  You started out by telling us the "Y" (usage of std::vector), but the "X" part of the problem is better solved by using an associative container such as `std::map` or `std::set`.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you use a different type of container for this.
It looks like you can use a `std::set` (if you don't need to count the duplicates) or a `std::map` (if you do need to count the duplicates).
Here's a nested map outline to make it possible to lookup a certain car and iterate through the distances and counts for each distance.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <sstream>

int main() {
    // an example file
    std::istringstream file(
        "1 138 1 239 1 440 1 241 1 462 1 432 1 404 2 435 2 514 2 565 1 328 1 "
        "138 1 401 1 142 1 404 2 460 2 472 2 418 2 510 2");

    // some typedefs to make it simpler:
    typedef int car_t;
    typedef int distance_t;
    typedef int count_t;
    typedef std::map<distance_t, count_t> distcount_t;
    typedef std::map<car_t, distcount_t> cdc_t;

    cdc_t cdcount; // map car -> distances with counts
    
    car_t car;       // temporary variable to read a car
    distance_t dist; // temporary variable to read a distance

    // read car and distance until the file is depleated and use car and dist as
    // keys in the outer and inner map and increase the count:
    while (file >> car >> dist) ++cdcount[car][dist];

    for(cdc_t::iterator cdit = cdcount.begin(); cdit != cdcount.end(); ++cdit) {
        std::cout << "car: " << cdit->first << '\n';
        for(distcount_t::iterator dcit = cdit->second.begin(); 
            dcit != cdit->second.end();
            ++dcit) 
        {
            std::cout << '\t' << dcit->first << ' ' << dcit->second << '\n';
        }
    }
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/66oPj3nrM) and a [Demo using `std::for_each` and functors](https://godbolt.org/z/a9cEorsee)

Comment: With C++ 98 ,Both of your codes are giving this error `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/c++0x_warning.h:31:2: error: #error This file requires compiler and library support for the upcoming ISO C++ standard, C++0x. This support is currently experimental, and must be enabled with the -std=c++0x or -std=gnu++0x compiler options.` How i can resolve this issue?

Comment: @frincit Can you paste the full error somewhere, like https://pastebin.com/ and share that with me? I don't have access to a compiler that old so I can't reproduce it myself. The oldest I've tried it with was [gcc 4.6.4](https://godbolt.org/z/dcYW87abc) and it compiles it without complaining.

Comment: Above error resolved by commenting the C++0x_warning.cpp file .Now the program is executing , Next issue is i am not reading data from single  `file()`.Instead i am reading it from two variables `int car_no,int Daily_Distance_Km` .How to modify while  `while (file >> car >> dist)  ` for two variables instead of file ?

Comment: @frincit Open `file1` and `file2` and then `while(file1 >> car && file2 >> dist) ...`

Comment: Note I am not dealing with `istringstream file object` i have `int car_no,int Daily_Distance_Km` .How to work with  `while loop` now with two `int` generated at **run time not at compile time**?

Comment: @frincit Do you mean like [this](https://godbolt.org/z/M1Wo5oYMM)?